# show result of a variable in php echo value

Tags: php, html

I have a file in PHP to sum values of a JSON file (sum.php) and in this file i put:

```
    <?php

// Get json from url
$json = file_get_contents("file.json");
// Decode json into an array
//$json = json_decode($content, true);
$data =  json_decode($json, TRUE);

// Set default
$total = 0;

// Loop through the array created when decoding json
foreach ($data as $key) 
{
    // remove symbol from the end leaving only digits
    $value = substr(utf8_decode($key['initialContractualPrice']), 0, -1);
    // remove the decimal point
    $value = str_replace('.', '', $value);
    // replace the comma with a decimal point
    $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    // add this number to the total value
    $total += $value;
}

echo $total;

?>
```

In other file that haves a button with a `<input type="submit" name="soma" value="Somar Valores" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="sum.php"/>` to sum.php and when i click on this buttom doesn't show result on page.

How i resolve it, can you help me?

Comment: As a first step: [turn on error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) and report back with errors (if any).

Comment: i resolve it its a basic form i'm sorry to put this here :D

Comment: i also need to show the value of $total in the other file without redirect to sum.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add action in `<form>` tag not in submit button

```
<form action="sum.php" >

 <input type="submit" name="soma" value="Somar Valores" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
    $total += $value;
```

User this

```
    $total .= $value;
```

because it + is plussing two numbers but you have string and number. As I understand you want to have this values together. Am I wrong?

Comment: i have a file.json with all like this [link](http://www.base.gov.pt/base2/rest/contratos?&sort(-publicationDate)) and i need to sum all values of initialContractualPrice and show it on a webpage